# How to refresh grid after row delete in react ag grid

Tags: reactjs, react-router, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am working on react ag grid and I am using infinite scrolling feature of ag grid.
I want feature where I can delete row and grid will immediately refresh its data.
But "remove row" feature is not available for infinite scrolling.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#api-inserting-removing-rows

Can anyone please suggest me anyway achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a hint right there if you scroll down a bit:

> Adding / removing rows directly in the grid for infinite scrolling is
> not recommended as it will complicate your application. It will make
> your life easier if you update the data on the server and refresh the
> block cache.

And then scroll down to the "Insert And Remove Example", there's example code showing how to remove rows (with a mocked up data source):

```
function removeItem(start, limit) {
    // here you would make a call to your data source to remove the rows
    allOfTheData.splice(start, limit);
    // get fresh data from the source
    gridOptions.api.refreshInfiniteCache();
}
```

Comment: If you're not using infinite scrolling, see: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#transactions. There are a few different choices, the easiest might be: `var selectedData = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows(); var res = this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: selectedData });`. There's a demo showing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a use of the following grid api
`this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData)`;

If you are fetching the  data from server side, then get the data first and then call the `setRowData()` method.

Comment: This is only advisable when using the in memory row model

Comment: Not exactly before setting you can give a server call to get the data and once rowData is available then you can call the his.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData); function.